# Postgres/SQL subquery - return multiples columns per grouping based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Struggling with this subquery - it should be basic, but I'm missing something. I need to make these available as apart of a larger query.

I have customers, and I want to get the ONE transaction with the HIGHEST timestamp.

Customer

```
customer   foo
1          val1
2          val2
```

Transaction

```
tx_key  customer   timestamp   value 
1         1        11/22        10
2         1        11/23        15
3         2        11/24        20
4         2        11/25        25
```

The desired of the query:

```
customer   foo    timestamp     value   
1          val1    11/23         15
2          val2    11/25         25
```

I successfully wrote a subquery to calculate what I needed by using multiple sub queries, but it is very slow when I have a larger data set.

I did it like this:

```
(select timestamp where transaction.customer = customer.customer order by timestamp desc limit 1) as tx_timestamp 
(select value where transaction.customer = customer.customer order by timestamp desc limit 1) as tx_value
```

So how do I reduce this down to only calculating it once? In my real data set, i have 15 columns joined over 100k rows, so doing this over and over is not performant enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query please:

```
SELECT 
    T.customer, T.foo, T.timestamp, T.value
FROM Transaction T 
    JOIN
(SELECT 
    customer, max(timestamp) as timestamp
from Transaction GROUP BY customer) MT ON
    T.customer = MT.customer
    AND t.timestamp = MT.timestamp
```

Comment: I tried this one and it worked. The only issue that I had was that one of my extra columns (e.g. another value in the transaction table, a text value though) manifested an extra row in my result when I tried.

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, the simplest method is [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
select distinct on (cust_id) c.*, t.timestamp, t.value
from transactions t join
     customer c
     using (cust_id)
order by cust_id, timestamp desc;
```

Comment: Without comma after `distinct on( )`